# Memory Monitor in Android Studio - what is normal

Tags: android, memory-leaks, dalvik

I was running the memory monitor from android studio on an app I am performance testing.  The app has a camera activity as well as some web view activities.  When is start the app, I see the allocated memory hover around 16mb and the free memory hovering around 8mb while i navigate between all the different web view activities.

When I open the camera, the allocated memory of course shoots up, to around 28mb, but when I back out of the camera activity and continue just navigating between the web view activities, it stays up there around 28mb.  If i force garbage collection it drops down, so i know there is no memory leak, but i am wondering if this is expected or if i should see the allocated memory drop back down when exiting the camera.